# Using function with pointer arguments as an argument for another function

Tags: c++, c

How would I correctly pass a function with pointer arguments to another function as an argument and return the value?

I have a function which takes two arguments in form of pointers to 2 arrays (pos1 and pos2):

```
float distance(float *pos1, float *pos2){
   return sqrt(pow((pos1[0]-pos2[0]),2)+pow((pos1[1]-pos2[1]),2));
}
```

I would like to pass this function as an argument to another function:

```
float force(float mass1, float mass2, float(*distance)(float,float), float scaling, float *pos1, float *pos2){
   return distance(*pos1, *pos2); // how to correctly return the value?
}
```

Would this be the correct way of returning the value? Do I need to include the argumets of "distance" function in "force" function too?

Thanks!

Comment: `return distance(mass1,mass2);`

Comment: The thing here is that arguments you are passing are actually of type 'float*'. That is why I prefer writing asterisk next to type (and not using declaration with comma)

Comment: Apart from the other problems, `distance` seems to want to be passed two 2-element arrays. You don't have two arrays to call it with. (And computing any sort of distance given two masses seems dimensionally implausible.)

Comment: Which of the two tagged languages are you using?

Answer (score 1):

First distance has to be a 'function pointer' that gets two float* as arguments. So change 'force' signature to

```
float force(float m1, float m2, float (*distance)(float*, float*), float scaling)
```

Second, in the force body call distance with actual arguments, e.g.:

```
return distance(m1, m2);
```

And finally, when calling force simply pass the name of your function as argument:

```
x = force(y,z,&distance, scale);
```

The ampersand before the function name is usually optional.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to "pass" a function to another, because you can "call" one in another. I suppose you can simply have

```
float force(float mass1, float mass2, float scaling, float pos1, float pos2){
    float dis = distance(pos1, pos2);
    ......
}
```

The C programming language is Turing complete even without function pointers, and function pointers are relatively rarely used in practice.